# jquery jrowl size

Tags: jquery, jgrowl

How to set the jgrowl size to be as auto.Because if the the contents are more i thinks it wraps up the content.
can we set this something like

```
<script>
$.jGrowl.defaults.size = 'auto';
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There [does not appear](http://www.stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html#samples) to be any public methods for setting the width of the growl itself. Your best option may be to go into the css file itself, and change it from ~235px to something larger. Note that this isn't really *solving* a problem. In reality, causing long text to wrap is (generally speaking) the ideal behavior.

You may also be able to add some logic to the `beforeOpen()` method that estimates the width of an unwrapped child, and adjusts the width of that particular growl.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using the beforeOpen callback as follows:

```
$.jGrowl( "your message here", {
      life: 3000,
      easing: "swing",
      position: 'bottom-left',
      beforeOpen: function(e,m,o){
          $(e).width( "550px" ).height("108px");
      }
 });
```

Note that **e** refers to the container element that encloses your message. Therefore the above code does not set the size of the popup window itself but the content of the popup window. The popup window resizes appropriately to accommodate its content.